# Can someone please explain some things related to the for.Each() method?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript and at the moment just going through all the little chapters in w3schools about it. Even though I've been having a mostly good experience, sometimes the explanations are not thorough enough and I am left confused. My problem wasn't the forEach method itself, but instead what came along with it. Here I will insert the code given by w3schools:

```html
<p>Calls a function once for each array element.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = "";
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];
numbers.forEach(myFunction);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
}
</script>
```

There are two main things that I don't fully understand. Firstly, the line `txt = txt + value + "<br>";` confuses me a bit. I am confused as to why they added `txt` into the addition instead of just `txt = value + "<br>";`.  My second confusion is in the same line actually. You see, every time the code is executed, the value that is displayed changes. How does the program know to change the value when all that is specified is `value`? Wouldnt it just display the same value? I appreciate every response :)

Comment: Most of us avoid w3schools, partly for the reasons you cited in your question. Read up on forEach at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach instead

Comment: If you did `txt = value + "<br>";` it overwrites what was in `txt` before that iteration of the loop. End result would be only the string from the last iteration of the loop and all you would see in page is `25`. `txt = txt + value` combines the previous value with the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your second confusion:

The `forEach` function takes a function as its argument, which, in your case, is `myFunction`. Basically, `forEach` iterates over the array it is called on and for every iteration, that is, for every item in the array, it calls `myFunction` and passes the current item, its index within the array, and the array itself as arguments to this function. So `myFunction` is called multiple times, each time with different values for its arguments.

Regarding your first confusion:

The goal of the demo is to construct a string which consists of all the items in the array, and each item followed by a `<br>` element. The pseudocode for this would look something like this:

```
For every item in array:
    append item to txt
    append <br> to txt
```

To append to `txt` in JavaScript you use the `+` operator: `txt = txt + value` or in short `txt += value`.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first confusion: The goal is to append every value to the current text, so you have to append the current value (and a `<br>`) to the current text before appending it. Otherwise the text would be overwritten. Also possible is `txt += value + "<br>"` which will internally do what you see in the example.

Secondly the value which is used is a method parameter of `myFunction`. When using the function in `numbers.forEach(myFunction)` the function will be called once for every value inside the numbers array.

Sorry if I didn't quite get your second confusion.

Answer (score 1):

forEach is calling that method (myFunction) as it iterates through the elements of the array (which there are 5 elements to it).  For example, let's just plug in values so you can see what is happening the very first time it runs:

- myFunction(45,0,numbers)

This is because the first element's value is 45, it's index is zero, and the array itself is numbers. The next time it runs it calls:

- myFunction(4,1,numbers)

This is because the second element's value is 4, it's index is one, and the array itself is numbers..... and so on.

As to why it says txt = txt + value + "<br>";  This is so that it can incrementally build the txt variable to contain all of it, as it processes them one at a time.  Let's see what happens with the same first two times as above.

The first time it runs, the value of txt is "" (nothing).  So it'll be

- txt = "" + 45 + "<br>";

The second time it runs, the value of txt is now "45<br>".  So it'll be

- txt = "45<br>" + 4 + "<br>";

This makes txt now "45<br>4<br>".  When this is done doing all of them, you can see it'll contain "45<br>4<br>9<br>16<br>25<br>".

Comment: What does it mean by index though? Im kinda new to javascript

Comment: index is just a number referring to it's position.  If we're talking about a line of people.... you can be the first person in line, or the second person, etc.  The indexes for arrays though start at zero... programmers are weird like that.  So the first THING (in this case, the first integer) is at position 0, then 1, then 2... and so on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all best wishes to you learning JS. My advice to you will be to follow [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for getting a better understanding of the concepts. Coming back to your question:

> why they added `txt` into the addition instead of just `txt = value + "<br>";`

So, as @charlietfl pointed out in the comments, simply doing `txt = value + "<br>";` would overwrite the value in `txt` for every iteration so you'll end up having only `25 + "<br>"` as will be the data in `value`

> How does the program know to change the value when all that is specified is value?

The forEach method calls myFunction once for each element in array and the `value` parameter of `myFunction` holds the value of the current element being processed in the array, `index` holds the index of current element in the array and `array` holds the complete array on which the `forEach` function has been called. So, your code is equivalent to:

```html
<p>Calls a function once for each array element.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var txt = "";
var numbers = [45, 4, 9, 16, 25];

/*
numbers.forEach(myFunction);
The above for each can be replaced by this
*/

for (var index=0; index < numbers.length; index++){
  myFunction(numbers[index],index,numbers);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;

function myFunction(value, index, array) {
  txt = txt + value + "<br>"; 
}
</script>
```

You can read more about the `forEach` method at [MDN - forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Medium](https://medium.com/@abustamam/for-loops-vs-foreach-in-javascript-7a977278a39e)

Answer (score 0):

If `txt` were not on the right-hand side of the assignment, the code would only display the value of the last element of `numbers`—25.

The `forEach` method calls `myFunction` once **for each** `value` (at `index`) in `array`; so, the method would not repeatedly display the same value unless every value in `numbers` were the same.